# Display block não funciona no Safari

Tags: javascript, css, safari, display, style

Estou tentando alterar o css de um loading via javascript.

O element está como `display:none` e quando vou submeter altero esse elemento para `display:block` e o mesmo aparece na tela.

A questão é que quando testado no Safari do Mac simplesmente não funciona, já tentei alterar a classe, entre outras tentativas, mas não funciona.

Alguém já passou por isso?

**Segue o trecho do código em questão:** https://jsfiddle.net/pauloflesch/xpvt214o/24323/

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Isso aí não deveria acontecer. Coloca seu código na questão pra podermos avaliar melhor, por favor. Se possível crie um Fiddle ou um StackSnippet.

Comment: Sem código fica impossível de saber o problema.

Comment: @Phiter editei a pergunta e adicionei o código.

Comment: Já tentou substituir `position:fixed` por `position:absolute` para ver se funciona?

Comment: @hugocsl testei e não funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize os métodos abaixo:

classList.add() e classList.remove();

Exemplo:

```js
$('#cadastro_pedido').click(function(){
  //document.getElementById('loading').setAttribute( "class", "loadingShow" );
  document.getElementById('loading').classList.add("loadingShow");
  document.getElementById('loading').classList.remove("loading");
  //document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'block';
  var contador = 10;
  setInterval(function(){
   if(contador < 90){
    document.getElementById('testePaulo').innerHTML= contador + '%';
    contador += Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
   }
  },1000);
  //document.getElementById("formProj").submit();
 });
```

```css
.loading{
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 99;
   background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   display: none;
  }
   .loadingShow{
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 99;
   background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   display: block !important;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loading" class="loading">
  <div style="color:#5fbbfb;font-size: 70px;width: 100%;text-align: center;float: left;position: fixed;top:35%;" id="testePaulo"></div>
 </div>
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" disabled="disabled" id="cadastro_pedido" >Cadastrar Pedido</a>
```